# Run script if on certain webpage

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I have a script that loads a music player but I only want to run it on my podcasts page.

It should go something like `if window.location is example.com/podcasts then <script> blah </script>`

How can I do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure, you need to check, whether you need a player in javascript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The javascript would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.location.pathname == '/podcast') {
        // script body here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! If i wanted to insert in the body a script like <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/js"></script> would this work? I dont have access to the script itself right?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can use some of the code Mike wrote below: 
$('body').append($('<script ... ></script>'))

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps but on this page if you use window.location you can do something like the following:

```
window.location['href']
=> "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709337/run-script-if-on-certain-webpage"
window.location['pathname']
=> "/questions/9709337/run-script-if-on-certain-webpage"
```

you can then do something like this if your using JQuery

```
if( window.location['pathname'] === 'desired_path') 
   $('body').append($('<script ... ></script>'))
```