# Run script if on certain webpage(s)

Tags: javascript

I've found this tread to run script on a certain URL. However, I'm trying to find a proper way  if there are more than one URLs. Let say I want to run script on every page in "make".

```
if(window.location.pathname == "auto/make/") {
        do something;
    }
```

[Run script if on certain webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709337/run-script-if-on-certain-webpage)

Comment: You could use a regex, but why are you even loading the script if you don't want it to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without introducing the additional complexity of regular expressions, you could just use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to determine if the path name starts with "/auto/make/":

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/auto/make/') === 0) {
    // do something
}
```

If you just want to make sure that the path name includes "auto/make/", but not necessarily at the beginning, you would do:

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('auto/make/') >= 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: So it won't match `fooauto/make`.

Comment: @undefined Thanks for catching the `)`, I assumed from the question that the path had to start with `/auto/make`. The question states *every page in "make"*, which is open for interpretation I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the string match :

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(/^auto\/make\//i){
    //do something;
}
```